# Play Integrity for Device accountDetails is UnEvaluated

Tags: google-play-integrity-api, google-play-internal-testing

My Device is fine. I have two gmail accounts logged in. Even few games are installed. But the Play Integrity is returning accountsDetail as unEvaluated.

Object Reference -

Unable to understand why is verdict is coming when the device is perfectly fine and genuine.

Play Integrity integration on my device.

Two Google Accounts is signed in in the device, Play Service is also enabled, Games are installed, so there is some activity in the account.

```
Google\Service\PlayIntegrity\DecodeIntegrityTokenResponse {#393
  +tokenPayloadExternal: Google\Service\PlayIntegrity\TokenPayloadExternal {#407
    +accountDetails: Google\Service\PlayIntegrity\AccountDetails {#404
      +accountActivity: null
      #accountActivityType: "Google\Service\PlayIntegrity\AccountActivity"
      #accountActivityDataType: ""
      +appLicensingVerdict: "UNEVALUATED"
      #internal_gapi_mappings: []
      #modelData: []
      #processed: []
    }
    #accountDetailsType: "Google\Service\PlayIntegrity\AccountDetails"
    #accountDetailsDataType: ""
    +appIntegrity: Google\Service\PlayIntegrity\AppIntegrity {#387
      #collection_key: "certificateSha256Digest"
      +appRecognitionVerdict: "PLAY_RECOGNIZED"
      +certificateSha256Digest: array:1 [
        0 => "zVdcyu2K6W5egOW67lpeGXPPi-sUSVb4J1g-71nFVaM"
      ]
      +packageName: "com.fastbanking"
      +versionCode: "234"
      #internal_gapi_mappings: []
      #modelData: []
      #processed: []
    }
    #appIntegrityType: "Google\Service\PlayIntegrity\AppIntegrity"
    #appIntegrityDataType: ""
    +deviceIntegrity: Google\Service\PlayIntegrity\DeviceIntegrity {#409
      #collection_key: "deviceRecognitionVerdict"
      +deviceRecognitionVerdict: array:1 [
        0 => "MEETS_DEVICE_INTEGRITY"
      ]
      #internal_gapi_mappings: []
      #modelData: []
      #processed: []
    }
    #deviceIntegrityType: "Google\Service\PlayIntegrity\DeviceIntegrity"
    #deviceIntegrityDataType: ""
    +environmentDetails: null
    #environmentDetailsType: "Google\Service\PlayIntegrity\EnvironmentDetails"
    #environmentDetailsDataType: ""
    +requestDetails: Google\Service\PlayIntegrity\RequestDetails {#394
      +nonce: "ZTIzMjk3ZDJhZmI1YzMyMDBlNWU5MTg4NGM1NTRiZTBkZmIxZGE4YjdlOGVkZTVkMjYyNmZjZjVkNTIzZmFlYjpmMzE3MGM5OC0yN2ZkLTQ2MzQtYjYzOS02YTM1MjkxZGNkOWQ="
      +requestHash: null
      +requestPackageName: "com.fastbanking"
      +timestampMillis: "1705742901428"
      #internal_gapi_mappings: []
      #modelData: []
      #processed: []
    }
    #requestDetailsType: "Google\Service\PlayIntegrity\RequestDetails"
    #requestDetailsDataType: ""
    +testingDetails: null
    #testingDetailsType: "Google\Service\PlayIntegrity\TestingDetails"
    #testingDetailsDataType: ""
    #internal_gapi_mappings: []
    #modelData: []
    #processed: []
  }
  #tokenPayloadExternalType: "Google\Service\PlayIntegrity\TokenPayloadExternal"
  #tokenPayloadExternalDataType: ""
  #internal_gapi_mappings: []
  #modelData: []
  #processed: []
}
```

Referenced Document - https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/verdicts
https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/account-activity

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/main/DiscoveryJson/playintegrity_v1.json

Risk is already verified and the app is perfectly fine working with other devices but currently giving issue in one specific device.

```
Device Information - Gives this Info - checked with Play Integrity under Play store settings 
Labels: [MEETS_BASIC_INTEGRITY, MEETS_DEVICE_INTEGRITY, MEETS_STRONG_INTEGRITY]
Build fingerprint: vivo/V2222C/V2222:13/TP1A.220624.014/compiler12011737:user/release-keys
Brand: vivo
Device: V2222
Model: V2240
TestId: dGVzdGluZy1iOTJhM2U0Yy02NzY5LTRmODYtOTQzYS03MWJhMGQxZjgzYWM=
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hey! Do you still have this issue? What exact verdict you are referring to? Could you maybe share the newer logs?